# Pre-order sorting of parents and children

Tags: sql, t-sql, sorting, preorder

Given the following data:

```
id  |  parent | sort
--------------------
  1 | null    | 0
  2 | null    | 1
  3 | 1       | 0
  4 | 1       | 1
  5 | 3       | 0
  6 | 5       | 0
  7 | 2       | 0
```

How do I do a pre-order sort, meaning parents first, then children, then grandchildren, etc...?

The sorted result I'm looking for is: 1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2, 7

If at all possible, I'd like to do this without using a CTE (or a CTE I can understand). The way I'm doing it now is just selecting every record and checking "upwards" to see if there are any parents, grandparents and greatgrandparents. It makes more sense to do something for the records that don't have a parents (top items) and let it go on until there are no children anymore, right?

I just can't wrap my head around this...

This is an oversimplification of my actual query, but what I'm doing now is along the lines of:

```
SELECT ..some columns ..
FROM table t
LEFT JOIN table tparent WHERE tparent.ID = t.Parent
LEFT JOIN table tgrandparent WHERE tgrandparent.ID = tparent.Parent
LEFT JOIN table tgreatgrandparent WHERE tgreatgrandparent.ID = tgrandparent.Parent
```

Comment: You need a recursive CTE for this.

Comment: Well, if I do, I do, but where to start?

Comment: Edit your question and include the code you are now using.

Comment: Are we guaranteed that any children will always have a higher `id` value than their respective parents? I.e. that changing `6`s parent to be `7` instead of `5` would be a data set that we don't have to deal with?

Answer (score 0):

This does use CTEs, but hopefully I can explain their usage:

```
;With ExistingQuery (id,parent,sort) as (
select 1,null,0 union all
select 2,null,1 union all
select 3,1   ,0 union all
select 4,1   ,1 union all
select 5,3   ,0 union all
select 6,5   ,0 union all
select 7,2   ,0
), Reord as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY parent,sort) as rn from ExistingQuery
), hier as (
    select id,parent,'/' + CONVERT(varchar(max),rn)+'/' as part
    from Reord
    union all
    select h.id,r.parent,'/' + CONVERT(varchar(max),r.rn) + part
    from hier h
        inner join
        Reord r
            on
                h.parent = r.id
)
select
    e.*
from
    hier h
        inner join
    ExistingQuery e
        on
            h.id = e.id
where
    h.parent is null
order by CONVERT(hierarchyid,h.part)
```

`ExistingQuery` is just whatever you've currently got for your query. You should be able to just place your existing query in there (possibly with an expanded column list) and everything should just work.

`Reord` addresses a concern of mine but it may not be needed - if your actual data is actually such that the `id` values are indeed in the right order that we can ignore `sort` then remove `Reord` and replace the references to `rn` with `id`. But this CTE does that work to make sure that the children of parents are respecting the `sort` column.

Finally, the `hier` CTE is the meat of this solution - for every row, it's building up a [`hierachyid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) for that row - from the child, working back up the tree until we hit the root.

And once the CTEs are done with, we join back to `ExistingQuery` so that we're just getting the data from there, but can use the `hierarchyid` to perform proper sorting - that type already knows how to correctly sort hierarchical data.

Result:

```
id          parent      sort
----------- ----------- -----------
1           NULL        0
3           1           0
5           3           0
6           5           0
4           1           1
2           NULL        1
7           2           0
```

And the result showing the `part` column from `hier`, which may help you see what that CTE constructed:

```
id          parent      sort        part
----------- ----------- ----------- --------------
1           NULL        0           /1/
3           1           0           /1/3/
5           3           0           /1/3/6/
6           5           0           /1/3/6/7/
4           1           1           /1/4/
2           NULL        1           /2/
7           2           0           /2/5/
```

(You may also want to change the final `SELECT` to just `SELECT * from hier` to also get a feel for how that CTE works)

Answer (score 0):

I finally dove into CTE and got it working, here is the base of the query if anyone else may come across it. It's important to note that `sort` is a padded string, starting at `0000000001` and counting upwards.

```
WITH recursive_CTE (id, parentId, sort) 
AS
(
-- CTE ANCHOR SELECTS ROOTS --
SELECT t.ID AS id, t.Parent as parentId, t.sort AS sort
FROM table t 
WHERE t.Parent IS NULL
UNION ALL
-- CTE RECURSIVE SELECTION --
SELECT t.ID AS id, t.Parent as parentId, cte.sort + t.sort AS sort
FROM table t
INNER JOIN recursive_CTE cte ON cte.id = t.Parent
)

SELECT * FROM recursive_CTE
ORDER BY sort
```

I believe this is the main part needed to make this kind of query work. It's actually pretty fast if you make sure you're hitting the necessary indices.

Sort is built up by expanding a string.
So a parent would have sort '0000000001', his direct child will have '00000000010000000001' and his grandchild will have '000000000100000000010000000001' etc. His sibling starts at '0000000002' and so comes after all the 01 records.